driver find element by ID
I need help uploading a photo to a work website. the following argument worked every page of the website except "select" button to upload a photo. I'm using:
login = driver.find_element("id", "ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_MainContent_tcMain_tpScanTimeDataSheet_apScanTimeDataSheetUploadNew_content_uplScanTimeDataSheet_ctl02")
login.click()

I tried Xpath and it still did not work on the "Select" button.
I greatly appreciate your help.enter image description here

You should use send keys to send the file's absolute path to the input.  Then use login.submit() (Selenium's convenience function to submit a form).  The file browse is outside of Selenium's scope.

You likely need to create a separate button element using something like
<button type="select" onclick="select()">Select</button>

The forum linked below may be useful:
How do I create a "select" button for a web app?

how do I associate it to the ID after creating the button?

You need to create a function that performs the desired action, and then insert that in the onclick attribute of your button. A great example of this can be found at
https://www.dofactory.com/html/button/id#:~:text=The%20id%20attribute%20assigns%20an,applied%20to%20any%20HTML%20element.

This answer is irrelevant; the question is about interacting with a specific element on a webpage. OP did not say they were developing this site
